# Spacing between list items

Tags: html, css

I’m having a problem with spacing.

My problem is that in

```
#dropdown ul li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

is adding the contents of that (method?) to before EVERY list item in this drop down menu.

I need it it just go between the first li. I feel like theres a way to specify that I just need it between the li of the first unordered list.

```
<div class=”dropdown”>
    <ul>
        <li> Services    /** I need it here somehow */
            <ul>
                <li>support center</li>
                <li>contact us</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> Products
            <ul>
                <li>Ball</li>
                <li>Truck</li>
           </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Help?

Comment: `#dropdown > ul > li:first-child::before`?

Comment: isn't that dropdown a class? shouldn't the selector be .dropdown instead of #dropdown?

Comment: YES! Thank you! Posted the answer that got it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#dropdown ul li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#dropdown ul li:first-child:before {
    content: "";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! Thanks!

```
#dropdown > ul > li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```